# why i cant publish package in laravel

Tags: laravel

When I Use php artisan vendor:publish  This Code Ask To me for chose Pack for publish and When i type package Number Like (10) and Press Enter I Have This Error

```
E:\laravel\okdd>11
'11' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

This is My Package's List When i type php artisan vendor:publish

```
E:\laravel\okdd>php artisan vendor:publish

 Which provider or tag's files would you like to publish?:
  [0 ] Publish files from all providers and tags listed below
  [1 ] Provider: Anhskohbo\NoCaptcha\NoCaptchaServiceProvider
  [2 ] Provider: Cviebrock\EloquentSluggable\ServiceProvider
  [3 ] Provider: Facade\Ignition\IgnitionServiceProvider
  [4 ] Provider: Fideloper\Proxy\TrustedProxyServiceProvider
  [5 ] Provider: Fruitcake\Cors\CorsServiceProvider
  [6 ] Provider: Illuminate\Foundation\Providers\FoundationServiceProvider
  [7 ] Provider: Illuminate\Mail\MailServiceProvider
  [8 ] Provider: Illuminate\Notifications\NotificationServiceProvider
  [9 ] Provider: Illuminate\Pagination\PaginationServiceProvider
  [10] Provider: Laravel\Tinker\TinkerServiceProvider
  [11] Provider: Shetabit\Payment\Provider\PaymentServiceProvider
  [12] Provider: anlutro\LaravelSettings\ServiceProvider
  [13] Tag: config
  [14] Tag: cors
  [15] Tag: flare-config
  [16] Tag: ignition-config
  [17] Tag: laravel-errors
  [18] Tag: laravel-mail
  [19] Tag: laravel-notifications
  [20] Tag: laravel-pagination
  [21] Tag: migrations
  [22] Tag: views
 >

  Aborted.
```

Comment: Type '11' when prompted by `php artisan vendor:publish` -- according to your output you are aborting the publish command and just typing '11' at the command line.

Answer (score 0):

I have had the same issue and I found that u could type this:

`php artisan vendor:publish --provider="Shetabit\Payment\Provider\PaymentServiceProvider"`

So you just write the provider name/path that you want to be published inside

`--provider="Here"`.

Unfortunately, I couldn't find the reason why this error happens.